# ExceptionsManager.js:73 RCTJSONStringify() encountered the following error: Invalid number value (NaN) in JSON write

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm having an issue with my React Native app on iOS. The following error happens every time the app goes from background back to foreground:

[image: error]

If I disable the remote debugger and go to production, the error is changed to:

```
RCTFatalException: Error calling RCTNativeAppEventEmitter.emit folly::toJson: JSON object value was a NaN or INF
RCTFatalException: Error calling RCTNativeAppEventEmitter.emit

folly::toJson: JSON object value was a NaN or INF Error calling RCTNativeAppEventEmitter.emit

folly::toJson: JSON object val... 
    Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation ___exceptionPreprocess
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib _objc_exception_throw
    Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation +[NSException raise:format:]
    musica_app RCTFatal
    musica_app -[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]
    musica_app __34-[RCTCxxBridge _initializeBridge:]_block_invoke
    musica_app facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::tryFunc(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)
    Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
    Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation ___CFRunLoopDoBlocks
    Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation ___CFRunLoopRun
    Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation _CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    musica_app +[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop]
    Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation ___NSThread__start__
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib __pthread_body
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib __pthread_start
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib _thread_start
```

I have absolutely no idea which plugin or setting is causing this? There is no information about a third party plugin available. I'm on React Native 0.48 and iOS 11 (but it also happens on iOS 10).

Comment: Are you using any library that listens to [AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html) or are you using default events for the AppState?

Comment: react-native-fetch-blob uses AppState, I already upgraded it to the latest package, the error still occurs but not so often anymore.